# Get an XML of a Table that contains XMLs

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've a table `@t_myTable` that contains XMLs like this

```
------
1. <xml><.....></xml>
2. <xml><.....></xml>
3. <xml><.....></xml>
------
```

Now, what I want is having a single XML containing all those XMLs.
I tried to solve this problem with this query

```
SELECT myTable.Value
FROM @t_myTable myTable
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('XML'))
```

but what I get is an XML with a lot of nested nodes, such us

```
<XML>                  <- the XML root as I want
  <myTable>            <- the name of the Table, useless in my XML
    <Value>            <- the name of the column, useless in my XML
      <xml>            <- the xml that I want to append to ROOT Node
        ....           <- ecc. ecc.
```

So what I want to ask is how can I do to minimaze the nodes in xml in a simplest way like this:

```
<XML>
  <xml>
  .......
  </xml>
  <xml>
  .......
  </xml>
<XML>
```

??? Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(xml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('<xml><a>Some a value</a></xml>')
,('<xml><a>Another a value</a></xml>')
,('<xml><a>And one more a value</a></xml>');

SELECT xml AS [*]
FROM  @tbl
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('xml')
```

The result

```
<xml>
  <xml>
    <a>Some a value</a>
  </xml>
  <xml>
    <a>Another a value</a>
  </xml>
  <xml>
    <a>And one more a value</a>
  </xml>
</xml>
```